# Automating two differerent model of same features into one model in R

Tags: r

Below is random forest model for two country.I have shared a small sample data for your reference and its model too.I want to combine this two model in to one customize model so that whatever outlier removal or imputations with respect to the country has to be happened. I tried my own R&D but i could not find a solution for it.

```
africa<-x%>%filter(country=="Africa")
India<-x%>%filter(country=="India")
```

#### Model for India

```
India<-India %>%
  mutate(Petal.Length= case_when(
    Petal.Length >= Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length,
    TRUE ~ Petal.Width))

India<-India%>%select(-c(country))

set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(India), replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
train_I <- India[ind==1,]
test_I <- India[ind==2,]

rf <- randomForest(
  Species ~ .,
  data=train_I
)

pred_inda = predict(rf, test_I)
```

#### Model for africa

```
africa<-africa %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Width= case_when(
    Sepal.Width >= Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width,
    TRUE ~ Petal.Width))

africa<-africa%>%select(-c(country))

set.seed(1234)
ind1 <- sample(2, nrow(africa), replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
train_a <- africa[ind==1,]
test_a <- africa[ind==2,]

rf1 <- randomForest(
  Species ~ .,
  data=train_a
)

pred_africa = predict(rf, test_a)
```

#### Data

```
> dput(x)
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 
5, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, 
5.4, 5.1, 4.6, 5.1, 4.8, 5, 5, 5.2, 5.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5.4, 5.2, 
5.5, 4.9, 5, 5.5, 4.9, 4.4, 5.1, 5, 4.5, 4.4, 5, 5.1, 4.8, 5.1, 
4.6, 5.3, 5, 7, 6.4, 6.9, 5.5, 6.5, 5.7, 6.3, 4.9, 6.6, 5.2, 
5, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 5.6, 6.7, 5.6, 5.8, 6.2, 5.6, 5.9, 6.1, 6.3, 
6.1, 6.4, 6.6, 6.8, 6.7, 6, 5.7, 5.5, 5.5, 5.8, 6, 5.4, 6, 6.7, 
6.3, 5.6, 5.5, 5.5, 6.1, 5.8, 5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.7, 6.2, 5.1, 5.7, 
6.3, 5.8, 7.1, 6.3, 6.5, 7.6, 4.9, 7.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.5, 6.4, 6.8, 
5.7, 5.8, 6.4, 6.5, 7.7, 7.7, 6, 6.9, 5.6, 7.7, 6.3, 6.7, 7.2, 
6.2, 6.1, 6.4, 7.2, 7.4, 7.9, 6.4, 6.3, 6.1, 7.7, 6.3, 6.4, 6, 
6.9, 6.7, 6.9, 5.8, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7, 6.3, 6.5, 6.2, 5.9), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 
4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 
3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 
2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 
2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 
2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 
2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 
3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 
3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 
2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 
3, 3.4, 3.1, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 
3), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 
1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 
1.5, 1, 1.7, 1.9, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 
1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 1.4, 1.6, 
1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 4.7, 4.5, 4.9, 4, 4.6, 4.5, 4.7, 3.3, 4.6, 3.9, 
3.5, 4.2, 4, 4.7, 3.6, 4.4, 4.5, 4.1, 4.5, 3.9, 4.8, 4, 4.9, 
4.7, 4.3, 4.4, 4.8, 5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.8, 3.7, 3.9, 5.1, 4.5, 4.5, 
4.7, 4.4, 4.1, 4, 4.4, 4.6, 4, 3.3, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3, 4.1, 
6, 5.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.6, 4.5, 6.3, 5.8, 6.1, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 
5, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 6.7, 6.9, 5, 5.7, 4.9, 6.7, 4.9, 5.7, 6, 4.8, 
4.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.1, 6.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 5.6, 5.5, 4.8, 5.4, 
5.6, 5.1, 5.1, 5.9, 5.7, 5.2, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.1), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1, 1.3, 1.4, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 
1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1, 
1.1, 1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 
1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3, 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 
1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2, 1.9, 2.1, 2, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 
1.5, 2.3, 2, 2, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2, 2.2, 
1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 
1.9, 2, 2.3, 1.8), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor"), 
    country = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Africa", "India"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-150L))
```

Comment: Why are you separating out the dataset into two datasets at the beginning? Could you not try running a random forest on the entire dataset and then analysis classification metrics at dataset level, then on a country by country basis? Also "outlier removal and imputations" are preprocessing steps that should be accounted for before you start training a machine learning algorithm